# How to get stdout of tar command

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I am trying to tar a file and get it's output store in a variable.
I tried this but it is not working:

```
resulting_tar=$(tar -zcf "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').tar.gz" folder)
```

Any idea how do I go about it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by output? The info that `tar` writes to stdout? The path to the created file? The binary data of the created file?

Comment: I mean the name of the file which is generated. Something like xxxx.tar.gz

Comment: By default, `tar` does not report the name of the file created.  In fact, it doesn't say anything unless you tell it to, and the options given don't tell it to say anything.  You'll need to capture the name of the file in a variable and report it yourself: `file="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').tar.gz"; tar -czf "$file" folder; echo "$file"`.  (Try running `tar -czf /dev/null folder`; you won't see anything from (most implementations of) `tar`.)

Comment: oh!. So, do you mean to say it is not possible to store the name of the created tar file in the variable

Comment: Yes; `tar` doesn't tell you what file it created.  You tell `tar` what file to create.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `tar` does not report the name of the file created.  In fact, it doesn't say anything unless you tell it to, and the options given don't tell it to say anything.

Note that `tar` doesn't tell you what file it created.  You tell `tar` what file to create.

You'll need to capture the name of the file in a variable and report it yourself:

```
file="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').tar.gz"
tar -czf "$file" folder
echo "$file"
```

Try running `tar -czf /dev/null folder`; you won't see anything from (most implementations of) `tar` — and that's not because I specified `/dev/null`.  Specify a name if you prefer: `tar -czf junk.tar.gz folder` and watch the (lack of) output — and remember to remove `junk.tar.gz`.

You might want to think about including the folder name in the `tar` file name, too.

```
folder="…whatever…"
file="$folder-$(date +'%Y-%m-%d').tar.gz"
tar -czf "$file" "$folder"
echo "$file"
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:** *No longer applicable after further clarification. Leaving for posterity.*

You're likely looking for both `stdout` and `stderr`. You can combine the two output streams by appending `2>&1` to your command:

```
resulting_tar=$(tar -zcf "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').tar.gz" folder 2>&1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but it doesn't help.
resulting_tar variable is still empty.

Comment: What kind of output are you looking for? Do you see it when you run it in the script without assigning it to a variable?

Comment: I am trying to get name of the file which is generated. Something like xxxx.tar.gz
No, I don't see it.

Comment: Some (all?) implementations of tar don't output the archive like that. However, you already know what it is supposed to look like.

Comment: If you edit and clarify your question to be "I want to get the name of the archive that gets created", I'll be happy to post another answer explaining how to do that.